# How to invoke action method by ajax on blur of input element

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm just starting to get my feet wet with Grails and I've started looking into using Ajax with Grails. I've looked at a couple of different examples but I'm still a bit unclear. Since I come from a JSF background I would like to pose a simple example in JSF and get the equivalent way of achieving the same thing with Grails.

The following piece of JSF code will call the someAction method of the bean when the blur event is triggered from the input component.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.someProperty}">
<f:ajax event="blur" action="#{bean.someAction}" />
</h:inputText>
```

So what would be the simplest way to achieve the same behavior with Grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails **[remoteField](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteField.html)** should do what you're looking for. Alternatively you can also accomplish the same thing with **[remoteFunction](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)**. In either case, the tags allow you to call a controller/action via ajax, and provide event hooks to process after success/failure.